# How to run configuration in eclipse directly from the command prompt using eclipse command?

Tags: java

I want to run configuration in eclipse with given VM arguments, program arguments, classpaths directly from the command prompt. I want to do this to avoid running a configurations again and again. Please help me out with this. Thanks.